# Connection error at SQL server 2008

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

This issue is related to the connection that I am having with sql server as I can't connect to sql server whenever I press the period key or just want to add the server name

Comment: why tagged javascript?

Comment: What error are you getting? What code are you using to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Explore "SQL Server Network Configuration" and then select "Protocols For MSSQLSERVER". Check your TCP/IP Protocols in right side pane. If it is disabled then enabled it and Restart the "Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER) service" that available in "SQL Server 2008 services pane".